# Add backburner debug to ember-cli project

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

[Ember guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/understanding-ember/debugging/#toc_errors-within-code-ember-run-later-code-a-href-https-github-com-ebryn-backburner-js-backburner-js-a) suggest adding `Ember.run.backburner.DEBUG = true;` to you app in order to get better stacktraces. Where should this line be added in an ember-cli project? I'm currently using ember-cli 0.2.5

Answer (score 2):

You add it in app/app.js, just before `App = Ember.Application.extend({`